# Access to rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I want to use `rails_admin` in my app. I don't use `device` or`cancancan` gems.

How can I deny access `rails_admin` dashboard if `current_user.admin?` is false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read this https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Customized-authorization

You could do something like that on `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.authorize_with do |controller|
    unless current_user && current_user.admin?
      redirect_to main_app.root_path, error: "Access Denied"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I have undefined local variable or method `current_user` error, my `current_user` method defined in application_controller.

Comment: `config.parent_controller = 'ApplicationController'` helped me, but redirect_to root_url does'n work properly

Comment: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Customized-authorization for fix redirect issue